# Craft on a cPanel hosting with CentOS and CloudLinux – I/O faults?

Tags: performance, hosting

I'm running Craft on our shared hosting with PHP 7.2. No SSD. Performance is fine, but working in the backend, I often get hickups of several seconds (!), where nothing happens, everything stalls.

Here's what cPanels resources diagram tells us:

[image]

So ... something with I/O and I/O Faults.

Could this be solved without changing the hosting?

Comment: Having you tried contacting your host to let them know what you're seeing? Shared hosting is tricky because you're contenting for resources (including disk I/O) with every other site that is hosted on that box.

Comment: Is the I/O thing a particularity of twig, yii, craft? Does it write a lot of files?

Comment: Not really?  99% of Craft's/Twig's writing on any given request will be in `craft/storage/runtime`.

Comment: Since the hoster raised the I/O limits, it's been going well. Still testing, but it looks like 2MB/s are required to avoid these timeouts